# How do I turn on `\v` by default for Vim/Neovim regexes?

Tags: regular-expression

After years of using Vim and then Neovim, I still find myself forgetting to escape parenthesis and the `|` character when I intend to use their special behaviour:

If I want to search for "this" or "that", this is incorrect:

```
/(this|that)/
```

Instead, I should have typed one of these two alternatives:

```
/\(this\|that\)/
/\v(this|that)/
```

I either have to backslash the `(`, `|`, and `)` characters, or I have to use `\v` to enter "very magic" mode. From the docs:

| `\v` | `\m` | `\M` | `\V` | matches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 'magic' | 'nomagic' |  |  |
| `$` | `$` | `$` | `\$` | matches end-of-line |
| `.` | `.` | `\.` | `\.` | matches any character |
| `*` | `*` | `\*` | `\*` | any number of the previous atom |
| `()` | `\(\)` | `\(\)` | `\(\)` | grouping into an atom |
| `|` | `\|` | `\|` | `\|` | separating alternatives |
| `\a` | `\a` | `\a` | `\a` | alphabetic character |
| `\\` | `\\` | `\\` | `\\` | literal backslash |
| `\.` | `\.` | `.` | `.` | literal dot |
| `\{` | `{` | `{` | `{` | literal '{' |
| `a` | `a` | `a` | `a` | literal 'a' |

How do I make `\v` the default mode, without having to type `\v` at the beginning of the regex?

Comment: `nnoremap / /\v` is a _very_ common mapping.

Comment: @romainl That looks useful. Is there something similar for substitutions?

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/13098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since search is done with <kbd>/</kbd> and search backwards is done with <kbd>?</kbd>, you can add these lines in your `.vimrc` in order to automatically type <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> when those buttons are pressed:

```
nnoremap / /\v
nnoremap ? ?\v
```

This doesn't affect the substitute command `:s`, I don't know how to automatically turn on "very magic" mode for those regexes.

Comment: I found this solution interfered with nvim-cmp, so I stopped using it eventually.

Comment: This breaks `/` + `Return` to search the last pattern because `/\v` followed by nothing matches everything.